# Probability measure and inequalities

Tags: measure-theory

I'm doing some old exam problems, and in almost all of them, there's asked a question of the following type:

> Let $\mu$ be a probability measure. Let $X =\{1,2,3,4\}$, let $\mu( \{1\}) = a$, $\mu(\{1,2\}) = 1/2$ and $\mu( \{1,3\} ) = 2/3$. Find lower and upper bounds on $a$.

In other words, some probability measure, a little bit of info, and we need to deduce something using the properties of a measure. I have problems with all of these, since I have no clue where to begin.

I would like to have this answered, but mostly I am looking for an answer which explains what the answerer was "thinking" whenever he chose to do something, and hopefully not just a $A \Longrightarrow B \Longrightarrow C$ answer in the most compact form possible, since that doesn't help me much.

Comment: Hint:  $a$ can't be $0$, say, because that would entail $\mu(\{2\})=\frac 12$ and $\mu(\{3\})=\frac 23$, whence $\mu(\{2,3\})>1$.  Assuming that $\mu(\{2,3\})=1$ gives a lower bound for $a$.

Comment: From $\mu(\{1,2\}) = 1/2$, we have $0\leqslant a  \leqslant 1/2$. 
From $\mu(\{1,3\}) = 2/3$, we have $0\leqslant a  \leqslant 2/3$.
From $\mu(\{1,2\}) = 1/2$ and $\mu(\{1,3\}) = 2/3$, we have 
$$ 0 \leqslant \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{2}{3}- \mu(\{1\})= \mu(\{1,2,3\}) \leqslant 1 $$
So $1/6 \leqslant a \leqslant 7/6$. Combining the three conditions, we have $1/6 \leqslant a \leqslant 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Denoting $p_{k}=\mu\left(\left\{ k\right\} \right)$ we find by means of the properties of a probability measure:

$p_{1}=a$

$p_{2}=\frac{1}{2}-a$

$p_{3}=\frac{2}{3}-a$

$p_{4}=a-\frac{1}{6}$

Also $p_{i}\geq0$ for $i=1,2,3,4$. These inequalities provide bounds for $a$.